# How to configure handler path to serve images from folder and database?

Tags: asp.net, handler, httphandler, imageresizer

I am using a handler to serve images from database. I have a problem with the path configured for the handler.

```
    <add name="DbFileHandler" verb="*" path="/images/db/*" type="DbFileHandler" 
resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true"   />
```

The flow we want to implement is:

1) First Image is requested from a folder say "/images/db".

2) If the folder doesn't contains the image, the handler is called which fetches the image form the Db, displays it and writes the image to the folder

Also we have implemeted [Imageresizer](http://imageresizing.net/docs) library to get images.

The problem here is when we request:

http://www.abc.com/images/db/101 -- Handler is called

http://www.abc.com/images/db/image.jpg?width=200 -- Image from folder is called
**http://www.abc.com/images/db/image.jpg -- Again Handler is called instead of calling the Image from folder**

How can we configure the handler so that a request to http://www.abc.com/images/db/image.jpg is not directed to the handler and instead served from "/images/db/" folder?

N.B: I would like to keep the path same i.e http://www.abc.com/images/db/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IIS express/full? If so, IIS is probably handling the `.jpg` extension as a static file and bypassing your handler. You need to set:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

This will ensure that IIS won't treat it as a static file and that your handler will run.

You'll then need to do the check manually to see if the image is there and serve that disk image if so, which is what IIS would do, but IIS would return a `404` if it wasn't found whereas you need to do your image processing and return the image data.

Answer (score 0):

**[Please read the ImageResizer Best Practices](http://imageresizing.net/docs/best-practices).**

Using ImageResizer properly, you only need to use DiskCache and the [SqlReader plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/sqlreader) (Or [build your own provider](http://imageresizing.net/docs/extend/virtualimageprovider)), and ImageResizer will handle request interception and (correctly threaded) caching for you.

Aside from the inherent performance limitations of using a HttpHandler instead of an HttpModule, under load you will create a lot of locked and/or corrupted files unless you implement a threading system that can coordinate the disk I/O.

I would strongly urge you to re-consider the approach you are taking here.